# can someone tell me how to change specific color to a caldroid calendar

Tags: caldroid

I'm working on an islamic app that show hijri calendar and also applying events like adding a specific date, time, event title and subject of that date so I want that when the app starts and displays calendar then the events' dates have different color.

```
caldroidFragment.setCaldroidListener(new CaldroidListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // caldroidFragment.setSelectedDates(date, date);
        Calendar text=Calendar.getInstance();
        text.clear();
        // text.set(Calendar.);
        int d=(int) date.getDate();
        int m=(int) date.getMonth();
        int y=(int) date.getYear();
        text.set(Calendar.YEAR, y+1900);
        text.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
        text.set(Calendar.DATE, d);
        hijridate.setText(HijriCalendarDate.getSimpleDate(text, 0));
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setBackgroundDrawableForDates` method of caldroid object and pass the map with dates as keys and `Drawable` as value. Something like this:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

final Map<Date, Drawable> backgroundForDateMap = new HashMap<>();
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// 1. date
c.set(2016, Calendar.MAY, 1);
backgroundForDateMap.put(c.getTime(), new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));

// 2. date
c.set(2016, Calendar.MAY, 2);
backgroundForDateMap.put(c.getTime(), new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));

caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDates(backgroundForDateMap);
```